# C memcpy error - memory could not be written on Windows XP

Tags: c, string, gcc, windows-xp, memcpy

I have a C program which loads a file line-by-line into one string and then memcpy's this string into another string pointer using this code:

```
   typedef struct inmod_struct {
       Int32 ReturnCode;
       Int32 Length;
       char  Body[ROWSIZE];
    } inmdtyp,*inmdptr;

    inmdptr inmodptr;
    char line[600];
    int doit()
    {
        char *p;
        p = inmodptr->Body;
        ReadFile();  //reads a line of the file into **line** string variable


    memcpy(p, line, strlen(line));
    p += strlen(line);

    inmodptr->ReturnCode = 0;
    inmodptr->Length = p - inmodptr->Body;

    reccnt++;
}
```

But when I execute the above program on my Windows XP SP3 machine, I get an error message box saying:

> The instruction at "<memory address>" referenced memory at "<memory address>". The memory could not be "written". Click OK to terminate....

I faced similar problem when I tried to do similar memory operations it is giving similar problems. strcpy works best for me but strcpy omits reads till NUL character of the line but I will have some more characters to be read even after NUL in the line. Can anybody please provide a workaround or any soultion for this.

Environment: Windows XP SP3, GCC compiler.

I even tried similar code compiling and usage on solaris unix and I am facing same issue there.

I have been facing similar errors with some of the OpenCV Python, C samples also.

**Edit:**
Sorry guys.. I have that pointer p initialized `p = inmodptr->Body;` inmodptr is a structure. and I can confirm that the pointer initialization is not the issue. Posted the full code for clarity

Comment: Your edit is wrong.  The pointer initialisation clearly *is* the issue by definition. You need to show us how  `inmodptr->Body` is initialised

Comment: `inmodptr` is a dangling pointer - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate a buffer and have `p` hold the address of that buffer.   Then you can use `p` like you did.

A pointer is a variable that holds a memory address.  Your pointer holds some uninitialized value which probably doesn't point to a valid memory address.

```
char *p = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
```

If you are storing a string the extra `+1` is for the NULL terminated char `\0`.  If you are using `memcpy` instead of `strcpy` for some reason, you'll have to manually NULL terminate your buffer.

Also if you `malloc` be sure to `free` once you are done using it.  You could also simply stack allocate an array of characters and use that instead of `p`.

Comment: the OP should also not forget to free the memory "free(p);"

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
inmdptr inmodptr;
```

declares a pointer `inmodptr`, but doesn't initialise it - it's pointing at some random memory location.

You need to make it point somewhere that can hold an actual instance of the `struct inmod_struct` object - for example:

```
inmdtyp inmod;
inmdptr inmodptr = &inmod;
```